# Composite Primary Keys and auto increment? What is a good practices?

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database, database-schema, saas

I'm developing SaaS app with multi-tenancy, and i've decide to use single DB (MySQL Innodb for now) for client's data. I chose to use composite primary keys like  **PK(client_id, id)**. I have 2 ways here,

**1: increment "id" by myself (by trigger or from code)**

or

**2: Make "id" as auto-increment by mysql.**

In first case i will have unique **id's** for each client, so each client will have id 1, 2, 3 etc..
In second case id's will grow for all clients.
What is the best practice here? My priorities are: performace, security & scaling. Thanks!

Comment: The first option really doesn't get you very much and has to be maintained.  Will this new table have a 1-many relationship with the client table?  What actually makes the record distinct?  If nothing, then use the auto-increment.  It really just depends on the situation.

Comment: As a follow up to the last comment, is client_id a foreign key?  That is, does it reference an existing id in the client table?

Comment: Your primary key should be just the autoincrementing id. Don't include the client_id, it adds no additional information. PK(client_id, id) with auto_increment id for innodb is only possible if you add an index(id), that will, again, add no additional information. And PK(client_id, id) with self-maintained ids will increase overhead while, again, add no additional information (e.g. you don't want to check new data insert by testing if id already exists to ensure data integrity - if you add a new row, you will just increase the id no matter what). So: PK(id) and an index(Client).

Comment: Yes the relationship is 1-many with client table, client_id is a foreign key with reference to an existing id in the client table!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely want to use autoincrementing `id` values as primary keys. There happen to be many reasons for this. Here are some.

1. Avoiding race conditions (accidental `id` duplication) requires great care if you generate them yourself. Spend that mental energy -- development, QA, operations -- on making your SaaS excellent instead of reinventing the flat tire on primary keys.
2. You can still put an index on `(client_id, id)` even if it isn't the PK.
3. Your `JOIN` operations will be easier to write, test, and maintain.
4. This query pattern is great for getting the latest row for each client from a table. It performs very well.  It's harder to do this kind of thing if you generate your own pks.

   ```
       SELECT t.*
         FROM table t
         JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) id 
                 FROM table 
                GROUP BY client_id
             ) m ON t.id = m.id
   ```

Comment: I just thought, that composite key will give me some sort of security (protecting from misspelled 'id' etc.), when selecting, between clients data, and maybe some scaling(sharding) pros in future. But looks like i'm just complicating things!)

Answer (score 1):

"PK(client_id, id)" --

```
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(client_id, id),
INDEX(id)
```

Yes, that combination will work.  And it will work efficiently.  It will not assign 1,2,3 to each client, but that should not matter.  Instead, consecutive ids will be scattered among the clients.

Probably all of your queries will include `WHERE client_id = (constant)`, correct?  That means that `PRIMARY KEY(client_id, id)` will always be used and `INDEX(id)` won't be used except for satisfying `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Furthermore, that PK will be more efficient than having `INDEX(client_id, id)`.  (This is because InnoDB "clusters" the PK with the data.)